# Get Workbook Connection Names

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how to get the list of the workbook connection names in Excel using VBA.

Comment: That is not clear, please expand on your question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the workbook connections dialog under the data tab to get this information?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will print all of the connection names to the debug window.

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  Debug.Print conn.Name
Next conn
```