# Translate an Excel Connection to an Access Query from external DB?

Tags: database, excel, vba, ms-access

I'm currently rebuilding a Excel document to Access, because it's become just like a database.

However in this old Excel file I connected to a DB (which I normally can't access, the IT dept. build the connection for me). I was wondering how I could change this connection to an adding query in my db. I want to extract just a few columns for the data, but I don't want my users to be able to adjust the original, that's why I want to copy the data, just like I used to copy it into my excel.

The connection now is build like this:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server;
SERVER=p-srv-sql;
UID=IDNAME;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
APP=Microsoft Office 2013;
WSID=PCNAME;
DATABASE=DBNAME
```

and the query was

```
select 
[Datum]
  ,[Tuignummer]
  ,[Tuignaam]
  ,[FirmaNummer]
  ,[Personeelsnummer]
  ,[Operator]
  ,[AssignmentNumber]
  ,[Info]
from Planning 
where WIDATU = ?
```

WIDATU was a range that I filled in to extract the query I wanted (for this query it was a date).

How can I add this to my access file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Was your old Excel workbook connected to an Access database? If so, did you have full permission to the Access db?  Have you tried opening Access and linking to the 'Planning' table, using the connection info you already have? If it's a permission issue, you need to work that out with your IT people (or the data owner). If you really do have permission, then we can help with a connection string.

Comment: Fairly sure that our DB is mysql or made in azure, to which i have no permissions. (Or at least not the info to access the DB). Our front-end is probably made in C# (Assuming this because I made similar front-end in the past in C#)

Comment: Can you look at your existing Excel connection(s)? That should tell you what backend you are using and give you an idea of what your connection needs to be in Access. Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273062/get-workbook-connection-names    or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837971/modify-existing-excel-connection-name-in-vba